# SQL Access query first date and last date for each series (c#.net)

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

[image]

I need to select first date and last date to each series

Answer (score 0):

I have the following solution using a subquery

```
select t1.person_id,
       t1.date as start_date,
       (
          select max(date) 
          from your_table t2
          where t2.date > t1.date and t2.date < ALL(
                     select date 
                     from your_table t3 
                     where t3.first = 1 and t3.date > t1.date)
       ) as end_date
from your_table t1
where t1.first = 1
```

Comment: this is not working cause its not an sql querry for c# program with access ( it  will work with sql server)